# How do I use overlay specifications for lists in org-mode's beamer export feature?

Tags: org-mode, beamer

It seems like `itemize` lists are automatically generated in the beamer export for org-mode. I can specify things like `<only@2>` for things like blocks, but it seems like I have to write out an itemize list by hand if I want to use it with an item. For example, I expect to type this and see one list item at a time, but I don't, I see them all in one slide:

```
*** Test
**** one
:PROPERTIES:
:BEAMER_envargs: <only@+>
:END:
**** two
:PROPERTIES:
:BEAMER_envargs: <only@+>
:END:
**** three
:PROPERTIES:
:BEAMER_envargs: <only@+>
:END:
```

Also, it seems like I should be able to do:

```
*** Test
:PROPERTIES:
:BEAMER_envargs: [<only@+>]
:END: 
- one
- two
- three
```

for the same effect, but I see the whole list. This doesn't work either:

```
*** Test
:PROPERTIES:
:BEAMER_envargs: [<only@+>]
:END:
**** one
**** two
**** three
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The org-mode Info node has some extensive examples (at least in the most up to date  development version).

The following minimal example should work exactly as you wish

```
#+LATEX_CLASS: beamer
* Section
*** Slide
   List
   #+ATTR_BEAMER: :overlay +-
      - item 1
      - item 2
```

Let me know if I misunderstood your request.

Comment: it turns out that the most recent version has addressed my needs since I posted this question, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: @JohnMoeller how ?

Comment: @Jocelyn delalande I don't remember. I stopped using org-mode a few months after this.